# How do I fix this error in my Django settings.py?

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization, settings, django-i18n

I am trying to make some translations using the i18n. I have imported some libraries in my TEMPLATES in the setting.py file.

The problem is that if I import django.core.context_processors.i18n my Iapp shows an error and it wont work.

my TEMPLATES in settings.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.core.context_processors.i18n', #i18n
        ],
    },
},
```

]

If I import the last line my app shows this error:

ModuleNotFoundError at /myapp2/
No module named 'django.core.context_processors'

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions of django this should be `django.template.context_processors.i18n`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-i18n